# python subprocess.call() not executing in loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I have the following piece of code that generates plots with gnuplot:

```
import sys, glob, subprocess, os, time
for file in glob.glob('comb_*.out'):
    fNameParts = file[5:].split('.')[0].split('-')
    gPlotCmd = []
    gPlotCmd = 'unset border; set xl "rotation period #"; set yl "T [K]"\n'
    gPlotCmd += 'set key above\n'
    gPlotCmd += 'set grid xtics ytics\n'
    gPlotCmd += 'set term post eps enh color solid\n'
    gPlotCmd += 'set xrange [20:876]\n'
    gPlotCmd += 'set output "fig_TestRelax-' + fNameParts[1] + '-' + fNameParts[2] + '-' + fNameParts[3]  + '-' + fNameParts[4] + '.eps"\n'
    conf = fNameParts[1] + '-' + fNameParts[2] + '-' + fNameParts[3]
    gPlotCmd += 'plot "' + file + '" using ($1/36000):($9-$3) w l lw 5 title "OP3-OP1 ' + conf + '", "' + file + '" using ($1/36000):($6-$3) w l lw 3 title "OP2-OP1 ' + conf + '", "' + file + '" using ($1/36000):($9-$6) w l lw 1 title "OP3-OP2 ' + conf + '"'
    fw = open('temp.plt','w+')
    fw.writelines(gPlotCmd)
    subprocess.call(["gnuplot","temp.plt"])
    print(file)
```

In the last loop execution the `subprocess.call(["gnuplot","temp.plt"])` does not seem to be executed. At the end of the program, temp.plt exists with data from the last iteration. Also print(file) is executed during the last loop. Also if I plot the temp.plt left after the program I get the last plot (so there is no problem on the side of the data). Only the line `subprocess.call(["gnuplot","temp.plt"])` is not executed. I also tried popen and monitor stdout and stderr but both were empty (as in all other iterations.
The checked the problem occurs both on linux and windows and in versions 3.3.5 and 2.7.3.

I conclude that there is something wrong with the script but I do not know what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One likely error here is that the file `temp.plt` isn't actually written to disk at the time you run gnuplot. Python doesn't necessarily flush its buffers immediately after a call to writelines. This would mean that when gnuplot is launched from your script, it sees an empty file. It doesn't give an error, because an empty input *isn't* an error, and it has no way of knowing its expecting anything else. By the time you run it outside of your script, Python has exited and hence can't be holding anything in its own buffers anymore.

Use the `with` statement to ensure that fw is closed once you're done with it:

```
with open('temp.plt', 'w') as fw:
    fw.writelines(gPlotCmd)

subprocess.call(["gnuplot","temp.plt"])
```

Answer (score 4):

@lvc's and yours answer are correct; it is a buffering issue and `fw.flush()` should fix it. But you don't need the temporary file, you could pass the input commands to `gnuplot` directly without writing them to disk:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen('gnuplot', stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(input=gPlotCmd.encode('ascii'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems I figured that out. I am missing fw.close(). The last lines of code should look:

```
fw = open('temp.plt','w+')
fw.writelines(gPlotCmd)
fw.close()
subprocess.call(["gnuplot","temp.plt"])
print(file)
```

Now the code produces the intended plots.

Comment: lvc thanks, I did not reload the window and did not see your answer, but the solution with close should be ok?